# Passing Parameter along with the URL - AFNetworking iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have a url like this.

```
https://<BASE_URL>/<TENANT_URL>/?query=where UserName = 'abc'&companyId=&page=1&pageSize=25&
filterResultByColumns=true.
```

I need to pass a parameter in this url. I am passing parameter as dictionary for the url

```
https://<BASE_URL>/<TENANT_URL>/
[dict setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"UserName"];
    [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"companyId"];
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"page"];
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:25] forKey:@"pageSize"];
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:@"filterResultByColumns"];
 //calling webservice
[manager GET:path parameters:dict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSError* error = nil;
                NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:responseObject

                                      options:kNilOptions 
                                      error:&error];
                success(json);
            }
                 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                     failure(error);
                 }];
```

But i got an error. What is the proper way to pass a parameter in the above url.

Error:

```
 { status code: 401, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    Date = "Thu, 16 Jan 2014 10:45:11 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0";
    "Set-Cookie" = "FedAuth=; expires=Wed, 15-Jan-2014 10:45:11 GMT; path=/path/, FedAuth1=; expires=Wed, 15-Jan-2014 10:45:11 GMT; path=/path/";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)}
```

I think this is a default error that i get when i fail with webservice. when i tried with postman, i got the response. My input request may not be proper. I need to send it like a above specified url.

Thanks

Comment: What you got as error?

Comment: in original url ther is "/?query=where" which i am not using in request. Is that any problem or how can i make a proper request.

Comment: I have sample code but it does not uses AFnetworking. Will it be OK to you?

Comment: @Ashu: Yes. i can use if possible

Answer (score 0):

I think, it related to authorization problem.Try this.

```
[manager setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:SERVER_USER_NAME password:SERVER_PASSWORD];
```

Comment: It's not an authorization problem. I think the parameter that i am passing is not proper.

Comment: @iPhoneGuy May be. But If error related to parameter means, you might not got this error.

Answer (score 0):

Though below code doesnot use AfNetworking, you can use it:

```
- (void) callWebService
    {
        NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your URL here"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];

        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *queryStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parameter1=%@&parameter2=%@",parameter1,parameter2];
        NSData *bodyData = [queryStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:bodyData];

        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;

        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                                 error:&error];


        if ([responseData length] > 0  &&
            error == nil) {

            NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                      options:kNilOptions
                                      error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@",responseDict)
        }
    }
```